# How to add another parameter to an existing method following SOLID principle in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

I have a method

```
-(NSData*)getCommonDataWithCommandID:(int)commandID withChannelNumber:(int)channelNo withDataArray:(NSArray*)dataArray withByteArraySize:(int)byteArraySize
{

}
```

This is called from a lot of places and have a big hierarchy of calling. How can I pass value from `dimSliderDecreasedTapped:` or `tapOnFifthChannel:`  This is just a portion!

[image]

Now I need to add another parameter to this method

> bool isFeedbackExpected

But this will violet [Open Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; I think you know *how* to add another parameter, so are you asking how to do it without disrupting the code base too much?

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, you want to add one new parameter to the method which you have implemented in your project and you have called that method from many classes. So there is no magic way to do this. You have to change the method as you want in the declaration and definition and then you can search the method in the project and make change in each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another method with that parameter:

```
- (NSData*)getCommonDataWithCommandID:(int)commandID
                    withChannelNumber:(int)channelNo
                        withDataArray:(NSArray*)dataArray
                    withByteArraySize:(int)byteArraySize
                     feedbackExpected:(BOOL)feedbackExpected {
      ...
}
```

and call this method from your original method

```
- (NSData*)getCommonDataWithCommandID:(int)commandID
                    withChannelNumber:(int)channelNo
                        withDataArray:(NSArray*)dataArray
                    withByteArraySize:(int)byteArraySize {
    return [self getCommonDataWithCommandID:commandID
                          withChannelNumber:channelNo
                              withDataArray:dataArray
                          withByteArraySize:byteArraySize
                           feedbackExpected:NO];
}
```

This will extend the functionality but it will keep the old interface. In Swift this would be even simpler because you could add an optional parameter (a parameter with a default value).

Comment: How do I pass feedbackExpected value to
- (NSData*)getCommonDataWithCommandID:(int)commandID
                    withChannelNumber:(int)channelNo
                        withDataArray:(NSArray*)dataArray
                    withByteArraySize:(int)byteArraySize
there are 4 to 5 layer hierarchy. How can I pass feedbackExpected value from those methods?

Comment: @ShuvoJoseph I don't understand your question.

Comment: I added image to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way, first one is to add parameter in existing method and you have to change every where that method is used(called). Second one is, make another method with that extra parameter and call this new method when you required so you not need to change other stuff in project

Comment: how original one become unused in second case? You are unclear with your problem i think!